# Bootstrap 4 gird layout customization

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to create a custom grid layout with Bootsrap 4. On the screen there would be 4 boxes. The top of the left would be a hyperlink with image. The top of the right would be a search box which height must have as tall as the search box is. The tricky part is a bottom section for me. The end of the bottom boxes should be the same. Now it looks like this:

```css
.custombox {
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: -2px 3px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.custombox:hover {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background-color:grey">
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">
      <div class="my-2 col custombox">
        <div>
          <img src="../Images/Image.png" />
          <h4><span>Some Text..</span></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="my-2 col custombox ">Widget 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center col-md-6">
      <div class="my-2 col custombox">
        Search
        <input type="search" />
      </div>
      <div class="my-2 col custombox">
        <label>
                        ASD
                        mklmlsmadlk
                        amslkédmklasmd
                        klmnaélksmd
                        émlkmaémsdémsa
                        éknaéslkndlkasn
                        anskldnaléksdn
                        anlksdnélkasnd
                        ansdknaélksdn
                        mklmlsmadlk
                        amslkédmklasmd
                        klmnaélksmd
                        émlkmaémsdémsa
                        éknaéslkndlkasn
                        anskldnaléksdn
                        anlksdnélkasnd
                        ansdknaélksdn
                        ASD
                        mklmlsmadlk
                        amslkédmklasmd
                        klmnaélksmd
                        émlkmaémsdémsa
                        éknaéslkndlkasn
                        anskldnaléksdn
                        anlksdnélkasnd
                        ansdknaélksdn
                        mklmlsmadlk
                        amslkédmklasmd
                        klmnaélksmd
                        émlkmaémsdémsa
                        éknaéslkndlkasn
                        anskldnaléksdn
                        anlksdnélkasnd
                        ansdknaélksdn
                    </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfrank01/5ma4y2ub/8/

Comment: What is the actual problem/question? What's not working with the existing layout?

Comment: Please check this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/bfrank01/5ma4y2ub/8/
As you can see my problem is with the left bottom box. It should be the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the combination of `d-flex`, `flex-column` and `flex-grow-1` to get this done.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6 d-flex flex-column'>
      <div></div>
      <div class='flex-grow-1'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 d-flex flex-column'>
      <div></div>
      <div class='flex-grow-1'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `row` is already flex display with stretch align-items (by default) that make the `col-md-6` has the same height. Then I change the display of `col-md-6` to be flex display and flex-direction to be column. Then set the second div in each column to grow to fit its parent with flex-grow.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1krxh73g/).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put the top boxes in a row and the bottom in an another row and set their bottom boxes height to 100%. So that the boxes can have similar height.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-6'>box 1</div>
        <div class='col-6'>box 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-6' style="height:100%;">box 3</div>
        <div class='col-6' style="height:100%;">box 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```